# Invalid request method DELETE using fetch

Tags: javascript

vanilla JS here, trying to use fetch to delete a resource via an api - getting the following error: "Invalid request method DELETE" - I'm able to Postman / curl the same endpoint without any problems and the status code upon completion is 204 in those cases. Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

```
function btnTrash(e) {
    var uuid = this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.id
    var url = "http://10.10.10.10:8080/api/v1/delete/" + uuid
    fetch(url, {
        method: 'DELETE', 
        mode: 'no-cors' 
      });
}
```

Edit: Managed to solve this - I wasn't setting the allowed methods on the backend `"Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, OPTIONS, DELETE")` and finally removing `mode: no-cors`.

Keeping in mind that removing `mode: no-cors` only works because I'm setting the `access-control-allow-origin` to `"*"` on the response.

```
function btnTrash(e) {
    var uuid = this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.id
    var url = "http://192.168.0.16:8080/api/v1/delete/" + uuid

    fetch(url, {
        method: 'DELETE',
    })
        .then(response => {
            if (response.status == 204){
                    // do something
            }
        })
}
```

Comment: Try to play with headers in Postman, I mean disabling some headers sent in Postman by default, like `Accept`. Once you find which one was required by the server, add it to your `fetch()` call.

Comment: Thanks for your comment - I found the issue in the end, it was a combintation of forgetting to set  the allowed methods on the backend and setting 'no-cors'.